# Chromecast not able to load and cast youtube videos in sender chrome app

Tags: youtube, chromecast

I am new to chromecast. I was trying to cast videos from chrome browser .I was able to cast mp4 videos but youtube videos give an error or just the YOUTUBE TV logo is casted not the actual video.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot cast YouTube videos based on their id's or anything of that sort. You can potentially write a custom receiver and embed an iframe YouTube player in your receiver but that is not a perfect solution either (for example, user won't be able to skip ads).

Comment: than what can be done to play youtube videos on chromecast from within the app

Comment: As I said, add an embedded youtube player to your custom receiver